# Why doesn't my script trigger a notice when accessing a value in an undefined array?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a test method which looks like this:

```
$row = $this->GetRowFromUserTable($id);
$this->assertLessThan(time(), time($row['last_update']));
```

When $row is null, access to $row['last_update'] should trigger an E_NOTICE and this test should fail, but it doesn't.

This code fails on first assert, so I know $row is null (fixture is the same):

```
$row = $this->GetRowFromUserTable($id);
$this->assertNotNull($row);
$this->assertLessThan(time(), time($row['last_update']));
```

When I write this:

```
$row = $this->GetRowFromUserTable($id);
$this->assertEquals(E_ALL, error_reporting());
$this->assertLessThan(time(), time($row['last_update']));
```

it succeeds, so I am also sure that error_reporting is right and this situation must have something to do with PHPUnit.

I use PHPUnit 3.5.6

I read this question:
[Can I make PHPUnit fail if the code throws a notice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679854/can-i-make-phpunit-fail-if-the-code-throws-a-notice)
but the answer suggests to use newer version of PHPUnit, but that answer is from 2009, so it's not it.

**EDIT:** I use NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 to run my test.

Comment: Unrelated: I guess you meant `$this->assertLessThan(time(), $row['last_update']);`, rather than `time($row['last_update'])`?

Answer (score 2):

Saidly "convertNoticesToExceptions" was my only real guess too (+1).

Could you write a `$foo = $undefinedVariable;` somewhere in the testcase to see if that also will not not trigger a notice // not fail the test ?

To check if your phpunit / php installation is working (and maybe narrow down the problem) you can try:

```
<?php

class myTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testFoo() {
        $x = $foo;
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

and run (note the --no-configuration part just to make sure you don't pick up a phpunit.dist.xml or phpunit.xml by accident)

```
phpunit --no-configuration foo.php
```

It show output:

> PHPUnit 3.5.6 by Sebastian Bergmann.
>
> E
>
> Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 2.50Mb
>
> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) myTest::testFoo Undefined variable:
>   foo
>
> /home/user/foo.php:5

Maybe that helps a litte

Comment: Ok, this test fails, so I have something to work with now. Is there any phpunit (CLI) parameter that would show me configuration parameters values used?

Answer (score 2):

The specific case you describe doesn't give an `E_NOTICE`. Accessing undefined keys of a defined array give an `E_NOTICE`, but strangely trying to access null values as an array doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have [convertNoticesToExceptions](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html) configuration property set to "true"?

Comment: Maybe I didn't express myself well. I don't expect execution to interrupt but PHPUnit to tell me that executing test method produced a NOTICE. I other words I want my test to fail if it cause a NOTICE.

Comment: I used xml configuration file now and set it explicitly - no chaggne. One more info: I use NetBeans IDE 6.9.1 to run my test.

Comment: Please move this to the comment area under the question.